# How to set Text font in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, printing, fonts, raphael

I have a small RaphaelJS script which makes use of Text to display text on the screen. This text is dynamic - it is updated frequently.

I want to set the font of the text. I have downloaded a Cufon .js font file to my liking, and used the code below to set the font. **except, it doesn't work!**

...The font is unchanged throughout. The colour is set, along with font-size, position etc. But not the actual font itself.

If I **Print** the text instead of using Text the font works fine. **But I don't want to do that** - it needs to be dynamic.

```
var text = paper.text(200,245,"--:--");

var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 600, 400) ;
var font = paper.getFont("FontName");
text.attr({ "font-size": 25, font: "FontName", "font-weight": 400, fill: lcdDisplayColour });

function updateText()
{
    /**
    .
    .
    .
    **/

    var newText = "some new text";
    text.attr({text: ""+dClockText});

}
```

In the HTML file I have:

```
<script src="raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="nameOfCufonFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have also tried:

```
text.attr({ "font-size": 25, font: font, ...
text.attr({ "font-size": 25, "font-family": "FontName", ...
text.attr({ "font-size": 25, "font-family": font, ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work fine:

```
text.attr({ "font-size": 25, "font-family": "fontName, sans-serif" });
```

Maybe you have some rule in css for font, which is overriding it?

Or maybe there is something wrong with your font, try this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

then set the font-family:

```
"font-family": "Pacifico"
```

Does this work for you?

BTW. Cufon fonts are for Raphael.print() method not for Raphael.text().

Comment: I **haven't** setup **any CSS** file for this HTML document - it's just a plain HTML doc with a title, and body. The scripts are contained within a div. That's it. Anything else it could be?

Comment: I would mention; when I use `text.attr({ "font-size": 25, "font-family": "FontName"...` it does go to **some Times New Roman-like font** (*not the one I've downloaded at all*). I even tried downloading the "whoa" font that Raphaeljs use on their fonts tutorial on their website, and it yielded identical results.

Comment: I modified the answer, please have a look

Comment: Thank you @san.chez I was able to use `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` to get it working. If there is a font that I want to use which is not in the Google font directory, but I want to embed it, how might I do that?